# populating values to a table from the same table based on condition and without condition

Tags: postgresql, insert, postgresql-9.3

I have a table named 'plot' which has columns such as 'id','tablename','geom','description'. I need to populate the geom and description of the plot table from the same table itself based on specific condition.For ex select geom,description from plot where id=2;But need to populate other tow columns 'id', and 'tablename' with different values.Is that possible in postgresql?

[image: sample_data]

Comment: Please be more specific: do you want to UPDATE existing rows, or INSERT new rows? (both are possible, based on existing rows)

Comment: insert new rows

Comment: can you provide some sample data and output. and from where that id should be defined? for what id we should insert geom,description and for what id we should insert id, and tablename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, something like

```
INSERT INTO plot (id, tablename, geom, description)
   SELECT 42, 'mytablename', p.geom, p.description
   FROM plot p
   WHERE id = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks.This is what i had expected.